# is there any way to do find solution for this title toolbar issue?

Tags: android, toolbar, title, titlebar

i have multiple fragments in one activity, while iam siwtching from fragment A to fragment B, iam hiding fragment A and starting frament B then on back press inside the Activity its showing fragment A again but with the title of fragment B..
the title it had been set from the data base inside the method loaddata() inside every fragment ,

so now how can i save the fragment title in fragment A before going to the fragment B and later use it again in backpress method in activity ?

Note: this two fragment take the data from data base and i have a lot of categories , i cannot use getActivity.settitle() with specific name , its need to be the last one that the fragmen A downloaded from data base

Answer (score 0):

Try to set title of toolbar inside `onResume()` method in the fragment. In this case, when you go back, it will call `onResume()` of coming activity from stack. calling `onResume()` will set the title of toolbar again